Vmware-modconfig can not load? Why?
I installed vmware and I got errors. I read the log as it told me to do but there is nothing I can do. I read the log there are some error codes and weird things and when I loaded wmware player, I got two messages in a loop.
Does somebody know what app I need if you know?
The image that pops-up:

This is the error that I always get:

I couldn't get the log sorry
